# Start Workflow using JavaScript or Ribbon Button

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, javascript, ribbon

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Foundation. I've developed a SharePoint-Farm Solution and now I want start a SharePoint Workflow clicking a Ribbon Button.

I know that with SharePoint Designer I can create a Ribbon Button that start a SharePoint Workflow but I've defined my Ribbon button inside my solution and I would perform this operation declaratively.

How can I perform this operation?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 5):

you can use **$().SPServices**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/sprc/Resources%20%20jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/sprc/Resources%20%20jQuery/jQuery%20SP%20Services/jquery.SPServices-0.5.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function StartWorkflow(ItemURL, ItemID) {
  var loadingImage = ‘Loader’ + ItemID;
  var workflowDiv = ‘WorkflowDiv’ + ItemID;
  //Show our loading image
  document.getElementById(loadingImage).style.visibility = ‘visible’;
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "StartWorkflow",
    item: ItemURL,
    templateId: "{04ee1c93-f6b7-49b3-a79c-fa3142ecd688}",
    workflowParameters: "<root />",
    completefunc: function() {
      document.getElementById(workflowDiv).innerHTML = ‘Workflow Started’;
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

[SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow)
[Start a workflow with Sharepoint (JavaScript)](https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/3873181)

You should also take a look to **Workflow WebServices** (/_vti_bin/workflow.asmx).
A solution can be create a Web Method (within an application page) that calls the method *StartWorkflow*. (you can call the web method from $.Ajax).

[Workflow Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981383(v=office.12).aspx)
[Workflow Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcworkflow.workflow_members(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Have you tried this code with SharePoint 2010? I know that I can execute this code only with SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Update the answer with an other possible solution

Comment: I was able to use Workflow.asmx and StartWorkflow method in SP2010 to run Nintex workflow, so SP OOB workflow should run as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
    function scriptStart(xSelectedItemId, xSubscriptionId) {

    //var xSubscriptionId = "{7d028513-b2ea-4ad0-a996-9b807f2beb2e}"
    console.log("scriptStartWF.js: Ribbonbutton script started, Workflow subscriptionId==" + xSubscriptionId + ", selected Item Id==" + xSelectedItemId)
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.WorkflowServices.js", function () {
                StartWorkflow(xSubscriptionId, xSelectedItemId);
            });
    });
}

//dialog element to show during processing
//var dlg = null;

//Subscription id - Workflow subscription id --> looked it up in App, does not change.
function StartWorkflow(subscriptionId, itemId) {
    fxShowInProgressDialog("Starten Workflow...");
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var wfManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web());
    var subscription = wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subscriptionId);
    ctx.load(subscription, 'PropertyDefinitions');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log("scriptStartWF.js: obtaining Workflow Property Definitions...");
            var params = new Object();

            //Find initiation data to be passed to workflow.
            var formData = subscription.get_propertyDefinitions()["FormData"];
            if (formData != null && formData != 'undefined' && formData != "") {
                var assocParams = formData.split(";#");
                for (var i = 0; i < assocParams.length; i++) {
                    params[assocParams[i]] = subscription.get_propertyDefinitions()[assocParams[i]];
                }
            }
            if (itemId) {
                wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemId, params);
            }
            else {
                wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflow(subscription, params);
            }
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function (sender, args) {
                    console.log("scriptStartWF.js: Workflow Started...")
                    fxCloseInProgressDialog();
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    fxCloseInProgressDialog();
                    alert('Failed to run workflow, Error: ' + args.get_message());
                }
            );
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            fxCloseInProgressDialog();
            alert('Failed to run workflow, Error: ' + args.get_message());
        }
    );
}

function fxShowInProgressDialog(msg) {
        dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Een ogenblik a.u.b...", msg, null, null);
}

function fxCloseInProgressDialog() {
        dlg.close();
}
```

The XML of my Ribbon button looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <CustomAction Id="ScriptLink.jQuery" Location ="ScriptLink" ScriptSrc="~site/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" />
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.Scripts" Location ="ScriptLink" ScriptSrc="~site/Scripts/scriptStartWF.js" />

  <CustomAction Id="d1d06df8-d6aa-40ff-8e5c-eeaed3ccbb0e.RibbonBtnStartWfNewWI"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="101"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="Invoke &apos;RibbonBtnStartWfNewWI&apos; action">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.RibbonBtnStartWfNewWIButton"
                  Alt="Request RibbonBtnStartWfNewWI"
                  Sequence="100"
                  Command="Invoke_RibbonBtnStartWfNewWIButtonRequest"
                  LabelText="Start Workflow Werkinstr."
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
                  Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>

      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonBtnStartWfNewWIButtonRequest" 
                          CommandAction="javascript: 
                                        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                                        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(this.ctx);
                                        var cnt = selectedItems.length; 
                                        if (cnt == 1) {
                                          scriptStart({SelectedItemId}, '{7d028513-b2ea-4ad0-a996-9b807f2beb2e}'); 
                                        }
                                        else {
                                          alert(cnt + ' items geselecteerd. Selecteer precies 1 item a.u.b.');
                                        }"
                          />    
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

for more info check [blogpost](http://www.xyzar.nl/?p=99)

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I don't think it will work with 2010 workflows. It works with 2013 workflows only.

Comment: mmm didn't know that, good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function() { $().SPServices({ operation: "StartWorkflow", item:"../../Workflows/SubmitWF/SubmitWF.xoml", templateId:"{04ee1c93-f6b7-49b3-a79c-fa3142ecd688}", worflowParameters:"<root/>" }); }); </script>
```

http://ctp009602c:9090/sites/fcsm/Draft%20Document/Forms/CustomDisplay.aspx 
Doesn't call workflow in sharepoint 2013....